# Configure styling of OSM with T-Rex vector tile server

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, vector-tiles, tile-server

I am using **T-Rex** as vector tileserver, **osm2pgsql** for importing the .osm.pbf file into the PostGIS database (table format - *planet_osm_line, planet_osm, point, planet_osm_polygon, planet_osm_road*).

I want to display the osm vector tiles with style of osm-bright.

T-Rex is using .toml configuration file, where are specified layers with sql queries.

Do you have such a pre-configured style configuration for mentioned table structure ?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: No, I haven't solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got my config.toml file generated from t-rex automatically. I used following command:

`docker run -p 6767:6767 -v $PWD:/var/data/in:ro -v /tmp:/var/data/out sourcepole/t-rex genconfig --dbconn=postgresql://johndoe@docker.for.mac.localhost:5432/osm`